# Set ng-model from directive using value passed by json

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I've a directive that include an HTML file based on a scope variable that is set calling a json in a scope function.

```
my.directive('myType', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {       
         $scope.$watch('aType', function(newVal, oldVal) {
           var myHTML;
           if ($scope.aType==1) myHTML = "aaaa";
           if ($scope.aType==2) myHTML = "bbbb"; 
           $scope.contentUrl = 'library/template/tmp-' + myHTML + '.html';
         });   
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
  };
});
```

In HTML file there is an input text with ng-model that i've to set correctly.
If i try to set it from the same function that read json I have always the previous value and not the current one.

I think i have to set in directly in directive, but i don't know how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ABOS you don't call `$apply` inside `$watch` will create digest in progress error

Comment: A demo replicating this issue would help. Can set up multiple include files on [plunker](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: You will have to eleborate more. Can you give us an example of what you are doing. Maybe you are just overlooking something. Directives are mainly used for DOM manipulation. I think you should implement a factory.